# Javascript Books for Pure Noob

Tags: javascript

this site has been a great help to me. I am working as a UI designer, and i am very interested in learning Javascript, but i am not able to find a right way to start from. I don't have a programming background.

I need a book for Javascript, which is totally for a Noobs, starting from the fundamentals. I tried reading Douglas Crockford's Javascript the good parts, but i wasn't able to understand much.

Please suggest me some books

Answer (score 6):

Try out this new site:

http://www.codecademy.com

It really will help you get a hang of javascript. It's an interactive way for learning javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a book, I'd recommend O'Reilly's Head First JavaScript. You can get it from [their site](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527747) or cheaper from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527748).

Comment: I'm using that book now, its pretty good.

Comment: thanks.. this book seems nice

Answer (score 1):

I started recently using [eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) and it is indeed a good book. Along with that Mozilla Documentation helped. But the best way to understand the language is to use it and see it in action. Ask a friend of yours to introduce you to firebug and how firebug is used to alongside with Javascript debugging. That will help you to get a grasp of how javascript is used to real world. Once you know that you will find that Javascript as a language is really simple, it's applications (and concepts such as AJAX) and it's libraries (jquery) are the ones that are making it really really powerful

Comment: i use javascript in my daily work, i download them and use them... but the thing is that i want to learn it and know how it actually works, i also use firebug, i will ask the developers to tell me how to use it for debug javascript.

Comment: thanks for your help... i will look for that book

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read [Pro JavaScript Techniques](http://jspro.org/). It is concise with a wealth of information.

Then there's the [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805531). Also make sure you get [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/) when it gets published.